# FPGA logic threshold - distinguishing a logic 0 and 1

Tags: digital-logic, fpga, xilinx, vivado, artix-series-fpga

I'm new to FPGAs and I'm trying to determine how an FPGA determines whether to register an input as a logic 0 or 1. The FPGA I am using is the Artix 7 and I would like to connect it to a function generator giving a square wave that toggles between 0 and 3.3 V.

In my constraints file I set the pins where I am connecting the function generator to the LVCMOS33 IO standard. Do I need to set the logic threshold as well or is it automatically set at 1.65 V since I have the standard at 3.3 V?

Here is the FPGAs [data sheet](https://docs.xilinx.com/v/u/en-US/ds181_Artix_7_Data_Sheet) for switching characteristics, but I haven't found any threshold information.

Answer (score 9):

The logic levels are shown in Table 8 of your referenced datasheet.

[image]

Comment: I wonder how they make the hardware to support selectable I/O voltages

Answer (score 1):

Although the above answer shows the DC voltage ranges for the input and output, the FPGA determines if the input should be a logic 1 or 0 by comparing it to a voltage reference (VREF). This depends on the FPGA you are using but for the Artix 7 in Vivado you can drag the voltage bank that your pins are assigned to the correct Internal VREF. In the following picture I assigned Bank 34 to a 0.9V reference. Anything above 0.9V is a logic 1 and anything below is a 0.

[image]

You can also define the voltage reference in your XDC constraints file using the following TCL command: `set_property INTERNAL_VREF 0.9 [get_iobanks 34]`.

Read more about how to set internal voltage references and the benefits of doing so on Xilinx's website [here](https://docs.xilinx.com/r/2021.1-English/ug899-vivado-io-clock-planning/Creating-an-INTERNAL_VREF-Constraint)